# Appending a dict to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm in the process of writing a program for the robotics team I'm apart of to gather data during competition to find the best team to "alliance" with. It needs gather about 20 values and needs to be able to list data by various parameters.  I have a lot of the framework done but it seems like when I append my data to the list it will change all entries to when I'm appending.

For example, if I have

```
data = [{"teamNumber":1345,"teamName":"Blah"}]
```

and try to append

```
{"teamNumber":3219,"teamName":"TREAD"}
```

to data using append() I end up with

```
data = [{"teamNumber":3219,"teamName":"TREAD"},{"teamNumber":3219,"teamName":"TREAD"}]
```

Currently we are adding data using this function(It has most of the unnecessary "meat" trimmed)

```
def inputTeamData(): 
    global data
    clear()
    temp = dataTemplate

    temp["teamNumber"] = question("Team Number?: ")
    temp["teamName"] = question("Team Name?: ")
    temp["foundingSeason"] = question("Founding Season?: ")

    save = question("Is the above data correct?(y/n): ")


    if save.lower() == "y":
        try:
            data.append(temp)
        except ValueError:
            print "ValueError. You gave me the wrong data types"
            sleep(1)

            else:
                print "Not saved"
                sleep(.8)
```

I don't know what gives, even though the answer is more then likely to be stupidly obvious I can't seen to find the problem.

Anyways, much thanks in advice to whoever can help me with this!

Comment: your simplified example does not show the error.  Please try again

Comment: What's the point of the whole `temp = dataTemplate` thing? I tested your code with `temp = {}` and it works well enough. Remember that keys in dictionaries do not (usually; in your case definitely not) need to be instantiated before adding data to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to learn some Python basics first:

```
temp = dataTemplate
```

does not copy `dataTemplate` to a new variable `temp`! Instead it gives the alias "temp" to the original dictionary which you had named "dataTemplate". 
You modify the same original dictionary each time when you write `temp[ .. ] =` because "temp" is just a alias for "dataTemplate".

You want

```
temp = dataTemplate.copy()
```

Comment: Heh, I knew it was something really simple.. Thanks for the help!